# StreamWriter only writes one line

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

I am trying to write from a .csv file to a new file.

Every time `StreamWriter` writes, it writes to the first line of the new file.  It then overwrites that line with the next string, and continues to do so until `StreamReader` reaches `EndOfStream`.
Has anybody ever experienced this?  How did you overcome it?

This is my first solution outside of those required in by my school work.  There is an unknown number of rows in the original file.  Each row of the .csv file has only 17 columns. I need to write only three of them and in the order found in the code snippet below.
Before coding the `StreamWriter` I used `Console.WriteLine()` to make sure that each line was in the correct order.

Here is the code snippet:

```cs
{
    string path = @ "c:\directory\file.csv";
    string newPath = @ "c:\directory\newFile.csv"

    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            string line;
            string[] columns;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                columns = line.Split(',');
                using(FileStream aFStream = new FileStream(
                    newPath, 
                    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
                    FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFStream))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(columns[13] + ',' + columns[10] + ',' + columns[16]);
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.WriteLine(sw.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `FileMode.Append` or simply move at end of stream.

Comment: Just curious is there a reason that you aren't using `File.AppendText(columns[13] + ',' + columns[10] + ',' + columns[16] + Environment.NewLine);` instead? Seems like a lot of code here.

Comment: You're opening (and closing) the `StreamWriter`every time you read a line.

Comment: @BigEZ3681 Just a warning that Excel has many quirks regarding CSV data particularly how it automatically converts some strings to dates/times/etc. and how it handles commas and quotes in strings. There is NO standard so you'll want to research those quirks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly fix your code, you'll want to structure more:

```
public void CopyFileContentToLog()
{
     var document = ReadByLine();
     WriteToFile(document);
}

public IEnumerable<string> ReadByLine()
{
     string line;
     using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(...))
          while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
              yield return line;
}

public void WriteToFile(IEnumerable<string> contents)
{
     using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(...))
     {
          foreach(var line in contents)
              writer.WriteLine(line);

          writer.Flush();
     }
}
```

You could obviously tailor and make it a bit more flexible.  But this should demonstrate and resolve some of the issues you have with your loop and streams.

Answer (score 2):

You should open the target in the same scope as you are opening the source instead of doing so in the loop which will cause you to overwrite the file every time with the `FileMode` option `OpenOrCreate`.

```
var path = @"c:\directory\file.csv";
var newPath = @"c:\directory\newFile.csv"

using(var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)))
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
{
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        var columns = line.Split(',');
        sw.WriteLine(columns[13] + ',' + columns[10] + ',' + columns[16]);
        sw.WriteLine(sw.NewLine);
    }
    sw.Flush();
}
```

I also hope you are sure about your CSV spacing as you are hard coding the positions in your code.

Comment: Your example could implement `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)` to cut down on some syntax, but nice example.

Comment: @Greg - I do'n think that would work, the OP wants to split the source based on `,` and then only write 3 of the values for every line back to the target.

Comment: @Igor - Thank you so much!  My goal with this solution is to first write the code above.  Then I will be creating a Windows Form Application to allow a user to select the file to StreamRead and a new file to StreamWrite to.  It will save the user on average an hour each day from having to open it in Excel and format it themselves.  I had created a VBS Macro, but one of the users this is intended for said that was still too much work.

Comment: @BigEZ3681 If you're opening an Excel File, I would suggest downloading EPPlus, will make it easier to interact with Excel.

Comment: @Greg- Thank you for the advice, I will download it.  The original data is read from a fuel tank transaction processor, at the end of the day it sends a comma-delimited file.  The first 10 colunmns are nothing but garbage.  I think the original programmer was trying to create headers because that is what the first 10 columns of each row of the original file contain.  "Self","Service","Date","Time", etc...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are creating and closing a write stream to the same file for every single line. This means the file gets overwritten every line. You want to take your using block outside of the while loop; however, if you insist on opening and closing the write stream for every single line, then you need to use FileMode.Append

```
{
  string path=@"c:\directory\file.csv";
  string newPath=@"c:\directory\newFile.csv"
  using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))) // no need for 2 usings
  using (FileStream aFStream = new FileStream (newPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
  {
    string line;
    string[] columns;
    {
      while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        columns = line.Split(',');
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFStream))
        {
          sw.WriteLine(columns[13] + ',' + columns[10] + ',' + columns[16]);
          sw.Flush();
          sw.WriteLine(sw.NewLine);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a working example of these corrections?

Comment: @levelonehuman I'm in Java land right now, but it's something like this